# How to Make a Manual Program for Support Vector Regression (SVR)?

Tags: optimization, svm, helper, manual, regsvr32

I am new for studying SVR and also program in Rstudio, to get graduation for my study, 
i would make some program to manual SVR. But I am stack, and nobody in website have the manual program of SVR. Please Help! Thankyou.

I have 10000 value data, and 8 (Price in this year, aksesbility, Fasility, the structur of soil, addres in the town, addres in sub distric, large, and type of soil) variables atributte from data time series in 3 years the price .of soil in my town.  I should predicted how much the price in the next three years.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Further, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Also learn how to post [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Oh Hi, Thankyou for your attention,